# Handling RxJava interrupted exception during instant search

Tags: java, android, rx-java, rx-java2, rx-android

I'm implementing an Instant Search with RxJava.

**Problem :** User starts typing some text on search `EditText`. User pauses for a while. It passes the `debounce` operation condition. Request process starts but before getting result of last request user starts to type more characters or changing the last text, now an `java.io.InterruptedIOException` will be fired. `onError` in Observer will be invoked and search `EditText` Observable will be disposed as well, so changing current text has no effect anymore and nothing happens because observable is disposed.

**Expected behavior** : Cancel previous request and continue searching with user's new input.

**Code** :

```java
        RxTextView.textChanges(etSearch)
                .skip(1)
                .map(CharSequence::toString)
                .doOnNext(this::handleSearchViewsVisibilityOnTextChange)
                .filter(string -> string.length() >= MIN_CHAR_TO_SEARCH)
                .debounce(SEARCH_QUERY_DELAY, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .switchMap(this::search)
                .distinctUntilChanged()
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(searchObserver);
```

```java
    class SearchObserver implements Observer<Result> {

        @Override
        public void onNext(Result result) {

            if (result.getItemsCount() > 0) {
                resultList = result.getItemsList();
            } else {
                // No result
                resultList = new ArrayList<>();
            }
            searchAdapter.updateData(resultList);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable throwable) {
            throwable.printStackTrace();
            List<Result> emptyData = Collections.emptyList();
            if (!isFinishing()) {
                searchAdapter.updateData(emptyData);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [retryWhen](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#retryWhen-io.reactivex.functions.Function-) with something like:

```
      RxTextView.textChanges(etSearch)
                .skip(1)
                .map(CharSequence::toString)
                .doOnNext(this::handleSearchViewsVisibilityOnTextChange)
                .filter(string -> string.length() >= MIN_CHAR_TO_SEARCH)
                .debounce(SEARCH_QUERY_DELAY, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .switchMap(this::search)
                .distinctUntilChanged()
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .retryWhen((errors) -> {
                    errors.flatMap((error) -> {
                       error instanceof java.io.InterruptedIOException ? Observable.empty() : Observable.error(error)
                    }
                 })
                .subscribe(searchObserver);
```

Comment: Try 'Observable.just(Object());' or anything that will call an onNext

Comment: It's not possible the error will be you are returning two different type of Observable in lambda